# How to grab and plot data from a PostgreSQL database via Chartjs

Tags: html, postgresql, chart.js

I have a index.js with localhost connection to my database and I can print in consol.log a query with value of my table.

**Input**

```
const {Client} = require('pg');


dotenv.config();

const client = new Client({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'postgres',
port: '5432',
password: 'mypassword',
database: 'mydatabase'
});

client.connect();

client.query('SELECT year FROM year_price_housing ', (err, res) => {
    if(!err){
        console.log(res.rows);
    }else {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    client.end();
})

client.query('SELECT price FROM year_price_housing ', (err, res) => {
    if(!err){
        console.log(res.rows);
    }else {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    client.end();
})
```

**Output**
[image]

But how can I send this query to my chartJS that it's in my index.html, my idea is change de X and Y random value for my query (x= year and y = price)

**Input**

```
<section class="chart-container" id="main-price-chart">
  <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>

  <script>
    var xValues = [50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150];
    var yValues = [7,8,8,9,9,9,10,11,14,14,15];
    
    new Chart("myChart", {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: xValues,
        datasets: [{
          fill: false,
          lineTension: 0,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
          borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
          data: yValues
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {display: true},
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 6, max:16}}],
        }
      }
    });
    </script>
</section>
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

instead of printing, assign to variables

something like:
var xValues = res.rows.map((val) => val.year);

(written from my head, I didn't test it)

You can also read about getting asynchronous data.
There are many examples.

you may want to check documentation first
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js